# Sort 2d vector while retaining columns

Tags: c++, sorting, multidimensional-array, vector

Say you had the 2d vector

```
[4][6][1][2]
[1][2][3][4]
```

How could I sort it so it would keep the 2nd row attached to the first one?

```
[1][2][4][6]
[3][4][1][2]
```

Comment: Can you show your 2d vector declaration?

Answer (score 1):

While sorting the first row, just iterate over rest remain rows and do the swaps on similar indexes.